# Adding SKLabelNode producing a lot of draw calls

Tags: sprite-kit, label, sklabelnode

How to reduce the number of draw calls when using a SKLabelNode?

This code will add 20 labels to the scene:

```
for(int i =0; i < 20; i++){
        SKLabelNode *label = [[SKLabelNode  alloc] initWithFontNamed:@"Futura-Medium"];
        label.position = CGPointMake(i*20+40,i*30);
        label.zPosition = 20;
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Label %i",i];
        [self addChild:label];//scene
    }
```

And the code above will produce 20 draw calls...Is this supposed to work like this? Or we can reduce the number of draw calls somehow? For example like we can do that with textures (using the atlases).

Comment: Yup, one draw call per label since each label has its own texture. Only alternative are bitmap fonts.